# iOS: SSL Handshake over bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, ssl

I'm trying to do a SSL Handshake over Bluetooth. I've been trying to use the Secure Transport API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport) to achieve this:

```
func sslHandshake() {
    guard let sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, .clientSide, .streamType) else {
        return
    }

    SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, { (connection, data, dataLength) -> OSStatus in
        //Read
        return noErr
    }) { (connection, data, dataLength) -> OSStatus in
        //Write
        writeToPeripheral(data)
        return noErr
    }

    SSLHandshake(sslContext)
}
```

I've been able to write the client hello data to the bluetooth peripheral without a problem. But before I can write the server hello that I get from the peripheral, the SSL handshake fails and when I try doing a `SSLRead` I get an error `-9806`.

Is there a way I can avoid the handshake from failing so I can write the server hello, cert and other stuff for the handshake?